# Good workout plan?

Tags: workout, glutes

Is this a good glutes workout plan?

Monday:

1. Hip thrusts: 100 kg
2. KAS glute bridges
3. Romanian deadlift: 70 kg
4. Abduction machine: 170 kg
5. Reverse lunges smith machine: 45 kg
6. Step ups smith machine: 10 kg
7. Sumo squats

Wednesday:

1. Glute bridges
2. Hip thrusts: 100 kg
3. Romanian deadlift: 70 kg
4. Reverse lunges smith machine: 45 kg
5. Step ups smith machine: 10 kg
6. Bulgarian split: 20 kg - Træk knæ tilbage mod bænk - escalator
7. Glute kickbacks: 7 kg

Friday:

1. Hip thrusts: 100 kg
2. Good mornings
3. Hyperextension: 24 kg
4. Single leg hip thrust:
5. Goblet squat to RDL:
6. Dumbell squats (workoutchristina):
7. Single leg leg press / single leg deadlift (krissy)

Comment: For....what purpose? And why nothing upper body?

Comment: You're forgetting bench press.

Comment: Some more info about your program would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factor here will be other body parts. (Lower back, joints, hamstrings) This is a large amount of volume for the glutes, but it also involves other muscles. 4 sets for 3 days in both shortened and lengthen position would be plenty of sets recommend for adequate muscle growth so long as progressive overload is being done, and you are recovering properly.